# Using the correct Property type

Tags: c#, properties

I am currently creating a program which requires me to use some properties. However I feel that the properties I am currently using may not be the best for the case.

These are the properties I am currently using:

```
// Returns the product name.
public string ProductName { get; set; }            

// Returns and sets the latest price. 
public decimal LatestPrice { get; set; }

// Returns the quantity
public int Quantity { get; set; }

// returns the total price of all the order items. (latest price * quantity)
public decimal TotalOrder { get; set; }
```

I feel as if the properties that only return something e.g. `ProductName` property should use a coded property that doesn't include `set;`

Alternatively, what would happen if I set them to a `private set`? would this be useful?

Would I be okay using these properties or should they in fact be coded?

I'm not actually getting any error codes just thought there may be a better way than how I am currently doing it.

Comment: Properties, or their read-only-ness, or their setter being private, are not "useful" *per se*. It all depends on what you want to achieve. For example, it doesn't make any sense to have a computed property (such as `TotalOrder`) be settable. It should be read-only and you'd evaluate `LatestPrice * Quantity` in the getter. Whether `ProductName`'s setter should be private or not depends on *who* can define a product's name. Generally, having lots of public properties with ` {get; set; }` are perhaps a design fault, OOP-wise. Unless you're dealing with a data transfer object (DTO) of some kind.

Comment: The only thing that seems clear to me is that `TotalOrder` should be computed from `Quantity` and `LatestPrice` rather than being an independent property. We don't have nearly enough context to know whether the rest should be read-only or not.

Comment: @Shaq p: Perhaps the MSDN article [Choosing between properties and methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229054%28v=vs.100%29.aspx "MSDN") might help you a bit. Properties have (mostly by convention) specific use cases where they are appropriate; sometimes methods should be preferred.

Answer (score -2):

If properties only return something, you could make set accessor private just as you mentioned.

However, it can not set the quantity and price throught property. You need to pass it in construtor.

For TotalOrder, you should implement the get accessor to make it align with updated LatestPrice and Quantity.

```
class Book
{
   　 public Book(decimal price, int number)
   　 {
         LatestPrice  = price;
         Quantity  = number;
     }
   　public decimal LatestPrice { get; private set; }
  　 public int Quantity { get; private set; }
   　public decimal TotalOrder { get{ return LatestPrice * Quantity;} private set{}}
}
```

Comment: **1.** Could you add an explanation to your answer what you want to say with that (malformatted btw.) code block? **2.** re: `TotalOrder`: An empty private setter is completely superfluous. If you want the property to be read-only, just omit the setter completely. **3.** *Why* do you suggest that `Quantity` and `LatestPrice` have a private setter? **4.** What about `ProductName`? Why did you omit it?

Comment: I'm relatively new to C# and from what I could remember about properties I had a feeling that auto-implemented code for those properties would not service me well. for all of those above properties. I will be using them for Methods that I am about to go onto coding. I added in the code to show what I had currently done as I was not entirely sure how to explain it all. but they will all be used to get their 'values' from another class. I have already created my contructor